# VBA Performance issue - Iteration

Tags: performance, vba, excel

I am reading a text file with 5000 strings. Each string contains Date+Time and then 3 values. The delimiter between Date and Time is a space, and then the three values are tab delimited. First string (strData(0)) is just a header, so I do not need that. Last string is just a simple "End".

The below code works, but it takes 1 minute to import into the worksheet! What can I do to improve this, and what is taking time?
Screen updating is off.

```
   'open the file and read the contents
    Open strPpName For Binary As #1
    MyData = Space$(LOF(1))
    Get #1, , MyData
    Close #1
    strData() = Split(MyData, vbCrLf)

   'split the data and write into the correct columns
   Row = 3
   i = 0
   For Each wrd In strData()
        If i > 0 Then 'first string is only header
            tmpData() = Split(wrd, vbTab)
            DateString() = Split(tmpData(0), " ")
            If DateString(0) <> "End" Then
                ActiveSheet.Cells(Row, 5) = DateString(0) 'Date
                ActiveSheet.Cells(Row, 6) = DateString(1) 'Time
                ActiveSheet.Cells(Row, 2) = tmpData(1)    'Value1
                ActiveSheet.Cells(Row, 3) = tmpData(2)    'Value2
                ActiveSheet.Cells(Row, 4) = tmpData(3)    'Value3
                Row = Row + 1
            Else
                GoTo Done
            End If
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Next wrd
Done:
```

Comment: You could take a different approach by copying the whole text file in Excel, the same way you can do manually (copy/paste) but programatically, and then delete the first and last row in Excel.

Comment: I am not sure I fully understand. How do I copy the whole text file programatically??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with something like this:

```
Dim Values(), N, I
N = 100
ReDim Values(6, N)
...
Do While Not EOF(1)
  I = I + 1
  If I > N Then 
    N = N + 100
    ReDim Preserve Values(6, N)
  End If
  Values(0, I) = ...
  ...
Loop
Range("A1:F" & i) = Values
```

The loop will work with arrays that in VBA are much faster than working with the sheet.

Comment: stenci, I like the look of this! Being able to manage all manipulations in memory and then in one go assign it to the sheet! Iwill have a go at this, too.

Comment: I had to add a transpose of the Values array but this works like a charm. Thanks stenci, I think I will go with this solution.

Comment: `Application.Transpose(Values)` should work. I'm Glad it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Excel can handle multiple types of delimiters (tab and space) with get data from text. This is what I have from macro recorder

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;C:\Users\jeanno\Documents\random.txt", Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
        .CommandType = 0
        .Name = "random_1"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 437
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = True
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

This will be much faster than string manipulation in VBA.

Comment: Thanks! This was quick! The .CommandType=0 is not accepted, but I took that out and it did the thing! However I now have a Header row which is a bit off (as I split date and time in two). The End staement at the end I can live with. I guess I could copy the file to a working area/sheet and then copy from this excluding the header and end row to the sheet where I want it. Any other ideas?

Comment: Or I could just rewrite the Header row after the data import, that is probably the simplest way.... Thanks Jeanno, I will save hours of waiting time on this!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you might be reading the file in Binary. Try the following approach. I ran 5100+ records and it parsed it in under a second.

```````````
Public Sub ReadFileToExcel(filePath As String, rowNum As Long)
'******************************************************************************
'   Opens a large TXT File, reads the data until EOF on the Source,
'       adds the data in a EXCEL File, based on the row number.
'   Arguments:
'   ``````````
'       1. The Source File Path - "C:\Users\SO\FileName.Txt" (or) D:\Data.txt
'       2. The Row number you wish to start adding data.
'*******************************************************************************
    Dim strIn As String, lineCtr As Long
    Dim tmpData, DateString

    'Open the SOURCE file for Read.
    Open filePath For Input As #1

    'Loop the SOURCE till the last line.
    Do While Not EOF(1)
        'Read one line at a time.
        Line Input #1, strIn
        lineCtr = lineCtr  + 1
        If lineCtr <> 1 Then
            If InStr(strIn, "END") = 0 Then
                tmpData = Split(strIn, vbTab)
                DateString = Split(tmpData(0), " ")
                ActiveSheet.Cells(rowNum, 5) = DateString(0) 'Date
                ActiveSheet.Cells(rowNum, 6) = DateString(1) 'Time
                ActiveSheet.Cells(rowNum, 2) = tmpData(1)    'Value1
                ActiveSheet.Cells(rowNum, 3) = tmpData(2)    'Value2
                ActiveSheet.Cells(rowNum, 4) = tmpData(3)    'Value3
                rowNum = rowNum + 1
            End If
        End If
    Loop

    Debug.Print "Total number of records - " & lineCtr 'Print the last line
    'Close the files.
    Close #1
End Sub
```````````

Comment: Thanks Paul, but I had the same timings for this solution! BTW the END detection is not functioning, but that I know how to fix. Problem is still performance. I have a fairly good machine so ít is not that.